# Convert a Histogram which has two variables plotted on it into a smooth Curve

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, matplotlib, histogram

Here is the code for generating the histogram. For the full code you can refer to this [iPython Notebook](https://github.com/djokester/KaggleKernels/blob/master/BreastCancerWisconsin/Breast%20Cancer%20Wisconsin%20(Diagnostic)%20Data%20Set.ipynb)

```
# Splitting the dataset into malignant and benign.
dataMalignant=datas[datas['diagnosis'] ==1]
dataBenign=datas[datas['diagnosis'] ==0]

#Plotting these features as a histogram
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=10, ncols=1, figsize=(15,60))
for idx,ax in enumerate(axes):
    ax.figure
    binwidth= (max(datas[features_mean[idx]]) - min(datas[features_mean[idx]]))/250
    ax.hist([dataMalignant[features_mean[idx]],dataBenign[features_mean[idx]]], bins=np.arange(min(datas[features_mean[idx]]), max(datas[features_mean[idx]]) + binwidth, binwidth) , alpha=0.5,stacked=True, normed = True, label=['M','B'],color=['r','g'])
    ax.legend(loc='upper right')
    ax.set_title(features_mean[idx])
plt.show()
```

[image: Histogram]

How do I convert this Histogram into a smooth curve with the area under the curve shaded/highlighted.

Comment: Can't you get the histogram data as an array and plot the array?

Comment: I think it will most probably create a kind of a scatter plot. I tried a lot of methods and none of them were what I was looking for.

Comment: Use https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html and https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/stats.html, having looked through google images for pics of your favourite probability density functions for appropriate distribution candidates.

Comment: It could be that you are looking for a [Kernel Density Estimation](https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2013/12/01/kernel-density-estimation/). Seaborn directly gives you a [`sns.distplot`](http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.distplot.html#seaborn.distplot) which shows this KDE curve.

Answer (score 0):

here is a simple example that might help you

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
np.random.seed(123)
datas = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 2, size=(100, 1)), columns=['diagnosis'])
datas['data'] = np.random.randint(0, 100,size=(100, 1))
```

I used numpy's [histogram](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html) function,but you could also use `ax.hist` with same arguments instead.

```
benign_hist=np.histogram(datas[datas['diagnosis']==0]['data'],bins=np.arange(0, 100, 10))
malignant_hist=np.histogram(datas[datas['diagnosis']==1]['data'],bins=np.arange(0, 100, 10))

fig,ax=plt.subplots(1,1)
ax.fill_between(malignant_hist[1][1:], malignant_hist[0], color='r', alpha=0.5) 
ax.fill_between(benign_hist[1][1:], benign_hist[0], color='b', alpha=0.5)
```

in the above example for plotting convenience instead of bin midpoints I just used 9 bin edges for demonstration.

in OP's code one could assign `hist_data = ax.hist(...)`
hist_data[0] contains histogram values and hist_data[1](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html) contains bins to fill in areas use something like

```
fig, ax=plt.subplots(1,1)
ax.fill_between(hist_data[1][1:],hist_data[0][0],color='g',alpha=0.5)
ax.fill_between(hist_data[1][1:],hist_data[0][1],color='r',alpha=0.5)
```

[image: filled histogram]